# Unable to kill a stage in Spark 1.6.1

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

There's a pending stage that is not being executed and I can't seem to kill it.

I did a simple pull of a small table limiting the results to make sure it won't overload (even if I didn't limit it shouldn't have had any issues)

The spark is running on AWS EMR- and has been up and running for 5 days without issues.

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo3Eb.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0HtX.png)

Comment: Could you paste the `Description` message in screenshot 1. That might give us a better idea.

Comment: Voting to close as abandoned, with clarification questions unanswered.